# Calculation of node betweenness from a weighted adjacency matrix

Tags: networkx

I have an adjacency matrix with the non zero elements indicating the weights of the link.The weights are decimals below 1 but are positive.  For example, consider the below matrix as the weighted adjacency matrix a

```
array([[0.  , 0.93, 0.84, 0.76],
       [0.93, 0.  , 0.93, 0.85],
       [0.84, 0.93, 0.  , 0.92],
       [0.76, 0.85, 0.92, 0.  ]])
```

I would like to obtain the node betweenness centrality of all the nodes in it. It is to be noted that my actual adjacency matrix is 2000 X 2000. I am new to networkx and hence any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

A=np.matrix([[0.  , 0.93, 0.84, 0.76, 0.64],
             [0.93, 0.  , 0.93, 0.85, 0   ],
             [0.84, 0.93, 0.  , 0.92, 0.32],
             [0.76, 0.85, 0.92, 0.  , 0.55],
             [0.64, 0   , 0.32, 0.55, 0]])

G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)


betweeness_dict = nx.centrality.betweenness_centrality(G,weight='weight')
```

The `betweeness_dict` will contain the betweeness centrality of all the nodes

```
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.13888888888888887, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.13888888888888887}
```

You can read more about the documentation [at this link](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality).